# How to determine SNR required for adding AWGN noise to clean IQ samples?

Tags: power, rf, signal

I'm doing an experiment w.r.t PSD output. I have generated some 11a  IQ samples and checking its PSD output in MATLAB using pwelch and comparing with the PSD output obtained using hardware.

Here are the block diagram  and output snapshots

wfm from VSG is transmitted at -10 dBm

[image]

[image]

I realized that VSG---> loopback cable ---> VSA   adds noise to the samples which results in noise floor whose level is at -90ish dBm/Hz . And when I was using pwelch function , noise floor goes down to -140ish dBm/z

To Make it more similar , I am adding some AWGn noise before I input to the pwlch function using MATLAB

iqSamples = awgn(iqSamples,SNR,'measured')

I was doing some trial and error for SNR value and using SNR =50 dB gave me the following output

[image]

Few questions here

1)  In this case ,**On what parameters does SNR depends?** 
2)  I' guessing this value might change with hardware and also loopback cable ? But what if I don't change the hardware , loopback cable used and VSG tx_power_level ?

Thanks for going through my simple question. Still trying to learn communications/DSP.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'On what parameter does SNR depends?'? I don't really get your question. Are you asking why the real-world system has -90dB/Hz noise in your specific case and the MATLAB sim does not?
(Also, what is the dB referenced to? Is this dBm? dBW? dB with respect to in-bound-power-level?)

Comment: I'm guessing the real-world system has -90dBm/Hz because it passes through VSG and then loopback cable and to VSA  which results in instrument noise etc to the samples ...  whereas  iqSamples which I'm using for MATLAB were clean (no AWGN--thats 1st snapshot)  and second one with AWGN noise..

Comment: out = awgn(in,snr,signalpower) ,  When signalpower is 'measured', the signal level of in is computed to determine the appropriate noise level based on the value of SNR     and  'the snr is measured in dB and signalpower is measured in dBW

Comment: To recreate similar behaviour , I used this function and added AWGN to iqSamples.... When I say parameters on which SNR depends , I'm under assumption that  VSG might have a technical specification where it says how much noise level hardware contributes (something like that).. sorry if I'm confusing myself and you too